# Accessing rows at a fixed interval

Tags: matlab, simulator

I'm looking for a way to update certain elements in a vector [nx113] for every full rotation of my system.

```
%% # Iterate through timesteps
for tt = 1:nTimeSteps
% # Initialise ink on transfer roller
rollers(2).ink = [zeros(1,98),ones(1,5),zeros(1,113)];

% # Rotate all rollers
for ii = 1:N
        rollers(ii).ink(:) = ...
            circshift(rollers(ii).ink(:),rollers(ii).rotDirection);
end

% # Update all roller-connections
for ii = 1:N
    for jj = 1:nBins(ii)
        if(rollers(ii).connections(jj) ~= 0)
            index1 = rollers(ii).connections(jj);
            index2 = find(ii == rollers(index1).connections);
            ink1 = rollers(ii).ink(jj);
            ink2 = rollers(index1).ink(index2);
            rollers(ii).ink(jj) = (ink1+ink2)/2;
            rollers(index1).ink(index2) = (ink1+ink2)/2;
        end
    end
end

% # Calculate average amount of ink on each roller
for ii = 1:N
    averageAmountOfInk(tt,ii) = mean(rollers(ii).ink);
end
rollers(18).TakeOff = averageAmountOfInk*0.6;

end
```

the vector rollers(2).ink is the vector i'd like to update. currently the vector is populated only once so i have ones from row 98:103. I would like this range of elements to be populated for each 'rotation' of my system not just the first time.
The reason - I'm trying to show ink being added intermittently from only a small section of the roller surface, hence the need for only five cells to be populated.
i thought that if i iterated from 1 to the number of timesteps, in steps size nBins-Max in the loop:

```
for tt = 1:nBins_max:nTimeSteps
```

this doesn't seem to be what i'm after.
I'm also hoping to remove ink from the system at the end. for every revolution i would like to be able to remove a percentage of ink on each rotation so it does not stay in the system (as if it was being printed onto a sheet and taken away).
Hopefully someone can understand this and perhaps offer some advice on how to proceed on either or both of my issues.

Comment: I'm trying to re-write this question in a more reader friendly manner to hopefully attract more interest in the question - so i'd like to delete this post! many thanks to high performance mark for the input, it's very useful however, due to the initial vagueness of my question i don't think it does what i'm looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explanation doesn't quite match your code (or *vice-versa* if you prefer) so I'm not entirely sure what you want to do, but the following may help you towards a solution or towards expressing your problem more clearly.

- The vector `rollers(2).ink` has 1 row and 216 columns, so an operation such as `rollers(2).ink(98:103) = something` is not updating rows 98 through to 103.  Note also that element 98 of that vector is initialised to `0`, it's not included in the elements which are initialised to `1`.
- You write that you want to update a range of the elements in that vector, then write a loop statement `for tt = 1:nBins_max:nTimeSteps` which strides over a vector of time steps.  Surely you want to write something like `rollers(2).ink(99:103) = new_values`.
- As for removing ink from the rollers at every rotation, you could just execute a line such as `rollers(2).ink = rollers(2).ink * 0.975` every rotation; obviously you'll want to replace the removal rate of 2.5% every rotation that I have chosen with whatever is right for your simulation.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! The vector for rollers(2).ink gets transposed at the output - sorry for the confusion, i'd actually forgotten about that!when i look at the variable rollers(2).ink it does actually have values on segments 98:103 so the concatenation does seem to do what i expect, i'd just like it to do this for every revolution and currently it does not! I had thought similarly regarding the takeoff (removal) factor. the way i'm considering it, the takeoff should actually be representative of the amount of ink which has been printed and so is no longer available to the simulator